Using Factory Pattern yields No qualifying bean for service interface injected into springboot controller
I am facing an issue with my spring-boot application. The API is using the factory design pattern along with JpaRepository. The API manages creation of "Route" which is "Road" in English.
This is my entity class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "route", schema="location")
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Route implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "route_generator")
  private long id;
  
  @Column(name = "route_type")
  private String routeType;
  
  @Column(name = "route_name")
  private String routeName;
  @Column(name = "route_width")
  private long routeWidth;

  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;
}

This is the Repository interface:
public interface RouteRepository extends JpaRepository<Route, Long>{

    Iterable<Route> findByRouteType(String route_type);

    int createRouteByType(Route route);
    
    int deleteRouteByRouteType(String routeType);
    
    //List<Route> findRoutesByQuartierId(Long quartierId);
}

Then I create the Routefactory class to delegate the creation of Route base on routeType.
public interface RouteFactory {
    public <T> RouteRepository getRouteService(String routeType);

}

Then I create the services for each routeType (nationalRoad, regionalRoad, provincialroad)
For nationalRoad type this is the service class:
@Service("nationaleRoad")
public class CountryRouteService implements RouteRepository{

@Override
 public int createRouteByType(Route route) {
        Route _route = new Route();
        _route.setRouteType("nationaleRoad");
        _route.setRouteName(route.getRouteName());
        _route.setRouteName(route.getRouteWidth()*4);
        _route.setDescription(route.getDescription());          
        save(_route);
    
        return 1 ;
 };

@Override
public int deleteRouteByRouteType(String routeType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
    ...
}

For regionaleRoad type this is the service class:
@Service("regionaleRoad")
public class CountryRouteService implements RouteRepository{

@Override
 public int createRouteByType(Route route) {
        Route _route = new Route();
        _route.setRouteType("regionaleRoad");
        _route.setRouteName(route.getRouteName());
        _route.setRouteName(route.getRouteWidth()*2);
        _route.setDescription(route.getDescription());          
        save(_route);
    
        return 1 ;
 };

@Override
public int deleteRouteByRouteType(String routeType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
    ...
}

Then in the controller I inject the RouteFactory in the constructor:
@Slf4j
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RouteController {
  
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RouteController.class);
  
  private final RouteFactory factory;
  
  public RouteController(RouteFactory factory) {
      this.factory = factory;
  }
  
  @PostMapping("/route/")
  public void createRoute(@RequestBody Route route) {
      log.info("Logging the Routefactory {}", factory);
      factory.getRouteService(route.getRouteType()).createRouteByType(route);
        System.out.println("Successfully Published the road = ' " + route + " ' to the 
      RegistrationTopic");
        
  }
}

When I run the project, it fails with Description:

No qualifying bean of type
'com.emura_group.country_geo_tracing.factory.RouteFactory' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
Dependency annotations: {}

The logger also displays:

Bean creation exception on singleton FactoryBean type check:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name
'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration':
No bean named
'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry'
available.

I change the constructor method of the RouteController to use @Autowired like this:
@Autowired
RouteFactory factory

but it still fails with the same message.
I tried adding @Service or @Component or @Repository to the RouteFactory but not to avail.
********** **EDITED** **********

I change the Services by autowiring the RouteRepository instead of implementing it just like @RoarS suggested:
@Service("nationaleRoad")
public class CountryRouteService{

@Autowired
RouteRepository routeRepository;
 public int createRouteByType(Route route) {
        Route _route = new Route();
        _route.setRouteType("nationaleRoad");
        _route.setRouteName(route.getRouteName());
        _route.setRouteName(route.getRouteWidth()*4);
        _route.setDescription(route.getDescription());          
        routeRepository.save(_route);

        return 1 ;
 };

public int deleteRouteByRouteType(String routeType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
    ...
}

And I removed the constructor from the RouteController leaving it this way:
@Slf4j
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RouteController {
  
private static final Logger log = 
  LoggerFactory.getLogger(RouteController.class);
  
  RouteFactory factory;
  
  @PostMapping("/route/")
  public void createRoute(@RequestBody Route route) {
      log.info("Logging the Routefactory {}", factory);
      factory.getRouteService(route.getRouteType()).createRouteByRouteType(route);
        System.out.println("Successfully created the road = ' " + route + " ' to the RegistrationTopic");
    
  }
}

And now I'm facing a nullPointer error indicating that RouteFactory factory is null in the controller:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
"com.emura_group.country_geo_tracing.factory.RouteFactory.getRouteService(String)"
because "this.factory" is null

When I try
@Autowired
RouteFactory factory;

The build generate the previous error:
No qualifying bean of type 'com.emura_group.country_geo_tracing.factory.RouteFactory' available: 

I implemented successfully the factory design pattern this way in a previous project but without JpaRepository spring JPA. I really need your help.

RouteFactory is just an interface, it doesn't put any beans into the context.

Yeah @RoarS. It is an interface. How can I then solved that. If it was a class I could have define it in the context this way: Bean
public RouteFactory routeFactory() {
return new RouteProviderFactory();
}. How can I solve this with interface definition? When I remove the controller construstor I get the error: No property 'createRouteByType' found for type 'Route

Start with a simple approach: Throw away RouteFactory. Create a single RouteService and inject RouteRepository into that service. RouteService should not implement RouteRepository. You should be able to handle all 3 route types this way. Good luck!

@RoarS. the creation of Road is different for each Raod type, which is the job of the factory design pattern, so if I Throw away RouteFactory, how can I tell the endpoint to delegate the relevant Road creation service ? And if RouteService desn't implement RouteRepository how can I also take advantage on the spring jpa predefined CRUD methods. I'm just a bit confused.

Just create a RoadFactory for that, start with a static method inside RouteService. You don't loose anything by injecting RouteRepository into RouteService.

Just to avoid any confusion: public interface RouteRepository extends JpaRepository<Route, Long> will add the repository to the Spring context, and it can be injected like all other beans.

Thanks @RoarS. the spring jpa part is now clear to me, the main issue is to dynamically call the relevant service when POST request is sent to the controller, and according to the routeType of the request create the type of road requested. Thanks for pointing that I could not autowire the interface
